# signalr send group notification with delay

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a signal r application. I have an issue of concurrent connection maxing out on iis. To avoid that i want my hub to send notification to groups created by in pack of 25 with delay of suppose 500ms. I add users to group as they connect. After count of 25 i add them to next group.Need help with how shall i send notification to each group with delay of 500ms. 
I have looped through the number of groups and used

```
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

but all connected users do not receive the notification

Comment: At the very least use `await Task.Delay(500);`, *not* Thread.Sleep

Comment: You may try to change settings : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667799/while-using-signalr-will-there-be-any-connection-limits-on-iis

Comment: How does delaying notifications reduce the number of concurrent connections?

Answer (score 0):

Your question almost describes the solution - buffer the notifications fro 500ms then send an array of all of them.

You could do that by pushing the notification in a queue or list and and use a timer to send the notifications every 500ms.

A far better solution though would be to use Reactive Extensions and the [Observable.Buffer(Timespan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229308(v=vs.103).aspx) method, thus avoiding queues and timers.

```
Subject<string> _subject;

.....
public void InitSubject()
{
    _subject=new Subject<string>();
    _subject.Buffer(Timespan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .Subscribe(notifications=>SendBatch(notifications));
}
....
public void SendBatch(IList<string> notifications)
{
    //Get hold of the SignalR context and send the notifications here
}

public void QueueNotification(string notification)
{
    _subject.OnNext(notification);
}
```

Buffer also allows you to batch a specific number of notifications, or use both a timespan and item limit to send a batch whenever one of the limits is reached.

Your code should call `QueueNotification` instead of sending the notification directly. Reactive Extensions also provide LINQ extensions, so you could apply filtering with the `Where()` method, eg to use different delays for different user groups, bypass buffering completely, or use any other combination.

You should note that since a Hub is transient, you can't put your subject inside the hub, although you can put `QueueNotification` in there, provided you provide a reference to the subject somewhere, eg by using Dependency injection to initialize the hub