# how to increase the concurrent connection of iis on window 10

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I developed an ASP.Net Web application with SignalR (WebSockets). I installed it on IIS on a Windows 10 Home Machine. Since SignalR uses a persistent connection between the server and the client I have the problem that only 10 concurrent connections can be handled with this setup.
how can increase the limit of concurrent connection of IIS on Windows 10?
is any way to increase the limit of concurrent connection?

Comment: only 10 concurrent connections seems remarkably low? [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667799/while-using-signalr-will-there-be-any-connection-limits-on-iis) have some information about tuning, but I think you've got something else working against you.

Comment: Actually, concurrent request number has defined as per operating system. Based on different version of your OS you can set up to 10 concurrent request which scoped by OS. You can [`get more details here in official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/request-restrictions).